# appear submit button web controls after 5 min using C# /JS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application where I want a submit button to appear after 5 min.

Into my Login page we crosscheck the userid password then send OTP, if user can't get OTP then we want to make appear after 5-10 min a new submit button(Generate OTP).

Comment: may be you can handle your need in c# code, instead of re-appear process. you can check last otp time is greater than 5 mins..then send new OTP otherwise show  msg OTP already sent

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setTimeout`() function available in `javascript`.
Or 
you can use [ASP.NET Timer Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

JavaScript Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function showButton()
        {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        function hideButton()
        {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            hideButton();
            setTimeout('showButton()', 1000);
        }

    </script>
```